# How to make stable video from yolo detections

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network, yolo

For a project I'm trying to perform action recognition for which I want the input to be as stable as possible (eliminate all other motion in de video).

The input videos for this action recognition I get from detections from a yolo network where I match the same object throughout the frames. But now my problem is that the detections from this yolo network are not always the same size and the objects are not always in the same spot in the detection. And just resizing the detections create unwanted motion in the video.

I've tried using a tutorial from learnopencv.org:
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/VideoStabilization

And made it so I can instead of using movies, can use .jpg files which I saved from the yolo-detections.
But these images should be the same size to calculate the optical flow between the frames.

A way that I think is possible is to use sift or some other kind of keypoint detector to match each frame and get rid of the motion in that way. But I was wondering if there maybe was something already made for this.

Has anybody an idea how I could crop or rescale the images to have the same to stabilize this?
Or maybe another way to tackle this problem?

Comment: its seems that you want a tacker on the detection rect. why not try to take out part of the code from opentld ?  check if the side box in this video is what you want to achieve 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hb4lpnW9r7w&ab_channel=AndyGikling

Comment: Yeah, looks like it! But i'm wondering if it also works when there are multiple objects in the frame? (context: action recognition on animals in a barn)

Comment: as long as it is a gradual movement. then it should be fine. like go and eat, go and walk. if suddenly 2 animal joint together.e.g mating. then there might be an issue in correctly predict the class or movement

Comment: Hmm, that is now the problem, they sometimes have sudden bursts that they begin to run and stand or lay next to or on top of each other.